# returns a list of all the unique words in a file in python

Tags: python, list

Write a function that takes three parameters, a filename and two substrings, and returns a list of all the unique words in the file that contain both substrings (in the order they first appear in the file).

For example, all the unique words in the previous sentence that contains the substring 'th' and 'at' are ['that']. Your function should pass the following doctests:

```
def words_contain2(filename, substring1, substring2):

    """
    >>> words_contain2('words_tst.txt', 're', 'cu')
    ['recursively', 'recursive.']
    >>> words_contain2('words_tst.txt', 'th', 'at')
    ['that']
    >>> words_contain2('/usr/share/dict/words', 'ng', 'warm')
    ['afterswarming', 'hearthwarming', 'housewarming', 'inswarming', 'swarming', 'unswarming', 'unwarming', 'warming', 'warmonger', 'warmongering']
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose = True)
```

actually Ive already tried do like this:

```
def words_contain2(filename, substring1, substring2):
    files=open(filename,"r")
    files_read=files.read()
    filelist=files_read.split()
    sub1=substring1
    sub2=substring2
    count=0
    result=""
    while count<len(filelist):
        if sub1 in filelist[count] and sub2 in filelist[count]:
            result = result + filelist[count]+","
        count += 1
    print result
```

but it returns result as `recursively, recursively, recursive, recursively`

In my opinion, there are two mistakes:

1. I got a string but not a list in my result
2. The question gives a example doctest which prints a word in the result list only once. In the file, a same word might appear more than one time.

I lost the original file `word_tst.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering a list for strings that contain a substring without maintaining uniqueness but order is way easy with filter function

```
not_unique = filter(lambda x:str(x).__contains__(substring1) and str(x).__contains__(substring2), content.split())
```

But we need to create a unique list with order maintained

```
def words_contain2(filename, substring1, substring2):
    file_ = open(filename, "r")
    content = file_.read()
    not_unique = filter(lambda x:str(x).__contains__(substring1) and str(x).__contains__(substring2), content.split())
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in not_unique if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Save result into `list datatype` and check if word already present in the result list or then. If not present then append word into result list otherwise ignore.

**Demo**:

```
result = []  #- Define result ad list data type
while count<len(filelist):
    if sub1 in filelist[count] and sub2 in filelist[count]:
        if not filelist[count] in result:  #- check already present or not
            result.append(filelist[count])  #- Add world into list

    count += 1
```

**Print result** in string format:

`print " ".join(result)`

---

We can use **for loop to iterate words** from the file:

**E.g.**

```
result = []
for word in wordslist:
    if sub1 in word and sub2 in word and not word in result:
        result.append(word)
```

---

Good practise to **close file object**

**e.g.**

```
fp = open(filename,"r")
files_read=fp.read()
fp.close()
```

or open file with **with statement**.

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    data = fp.read()

# do nest coding
```

---

**Note**: Give proper variable name.

e.g. **varaible name** like `wordslist`,  not `filelist`. So it is more readable for others.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way to a correct function. First of all, you are using a string instead of a list. You can create a list as follows:

```
result = []
```

Second of all, you are currently not checking if the word you found is already in the list. You can do this with the same keyword you are currently using: `is`

```
if not (filelist[count] in result):
    result.append(filelist[count])
```

You could also use a for-loop over your filelist instead of using a count:

```
for word in filelist:
    if sub1 in word and sub2 in word:
```